# Excluding XSD while generating Java files by WSDL2Java in CXF via Ant

Tags: java, soap, ant, wsdl, cxf

I have 2 WSDL for 2 different services which uses same XSD for Input and Output messages. Now I want to use CXF WSDL2Java by ANT target and create the server java file out of it one by one, but I don't want to recreate the java files in 2nd time which created earlier in 1st time. As both uses same XSD and almost all Input and Output parameter is same but the purpose of the service is different.

Kindly help me how can I achieve this by CXF and ANT.

Comment: IMHO the problem is more about Ant than CXF. It's about how to make Cxf plugin for Ant not to process again XSD files. Perhaps you want to change the title to be more specific.

Comment: Actualy I am not sure whether it can be done via Ant by passing some argument to WSDL2Java provided by CXF or not, but as you suggested I will also include Ant in the title.

Answer (score 0):

As CXF documentation says you can configure Ant to parse your XSD: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html
Maybe you can define two targets, one that results in your XSD files parser and java files created and a second one that does not need to do this. Later you can integrate these two targets with your Ant workflow as you need.